# Pandas how to find position of cell contains sub-string

Tags: pandas, numpy

Example:

```
Price   | Rate p/lot |  Total Comm|
 947.2      1.25        BAM 1.25

 129.3      2.1         $ 1.25

 161.69     $ 0.8         CAD 2.00
```

If I have search for ['$','CAD']:-

Expected output:-

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1),(2,2)]
```

Comment: But `['$']` is not in sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, find solution like this,It may help someone

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[947.2, 1.25, 'BAM 1.25'],
                   [129.3, 2.1, '$ 1.25'],
                   [161.69, '0.8 $', 'CAD 2.00']],
                  columns=['Price', 'Rate p/lot', 'Total Comm'])


row, column = (df.applymap(lambda x: x if any(s in str(x) for s in ['$','CAD']) else None )).values.nonzero()
t = list(zip(row,column))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in` with `applymap`:

```
i, j = (df.applymap(lambda x: '$' in str(x))).values.nonzero()
t = list(zip(i, j))
print (t)
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

---

```
i, j = (df.applymap(lambda x: any(y for y in L if y in str(x)))).values.nonzero()
#another solution
#i, j = (df.applymap(lambda x: any(s in str(x) for s in L))).values.nonzero()
t = list(zip(i, j))
print (t)

[(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Comment: buddy instead of '$' how can I check it for at least one string in list.?

Comment: Sorry got it. Can you check my answer and update if anything needed.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Super, I add solution too :)

Comment: Thanks , bro can I do same thing for series instead for dataframe?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - If Series, then is expected output positions?

Comment: `[ lambda x: x if any(s in str(x) for s in ['$','CAD']) else None,df['Total Comm'].tolist()]`, trying like this but it's giving all cells.

Comment: Not position it will gives string directly.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Now understand, need `s[s.apply(lambda x: any(y for y in L if y in str(x)))]`

Comment: `s = df['Total Comm']`

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - With column `df.loc[df['Total Comm'].apply(lambda x: any(y for y in L if y in str(x))), 'Total Comm']`

Comment: Bro sorry but I don't have dataframe I just have series and so for me it's giving `[False, True, True]` how do I convert it into values.

Comment: if `mask = [False, True, True]` then need `df.loc[mask, 'Total Comm']`

Comment: but I don't have df? I just have series.

Comment: Then use `series[mask]`

Answer (score 1):

Use `str.contains`:

```
df = df.astype(str)

from itertools import product
result = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [list(product([i],list(df.iloc[:,i][df.iloc[:,i].str.contains('\$|CAD')].index))) for i in range(len(df.columns))])
```

Output

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```